# Problems with accessing SQL Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two questions which have been impossible for me to fix all morning. 
1: Is about Microsoft SQL Management. 
When I try to connect to the Database through Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication I keep getting this error:

[image: Image 1]

I've been searching on google and tried to apply what I found on some pages/posts but I still keep getting this error.

2: About TextBox error in ASP.net
 I keep getting an error in SQL connection string. About the Textbox, not being found. 
the error is this :

> The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context

The code where it shows the error is this :

```
string cmdText = "SELECT 1 FROM Login WHERE Username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
```

There are 2 TextBox in the project, and as shown in this

```
<div id ="LoginPannel">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
```

The fun part of this is that the same form copied to a test project works.

Any help?

Comment: Were you able to access this instance of SQL Server before? Please open `Service Management Window` by typing `services.msc` and check for services starting with your SQLServer and check if your instance is **Running**

Comment: Do not post two totally unrelated questions.

Comment: @Steve I did not want to, but I did not want to make 2 different posts for suck simple question as the first.

Comment: also, where to write ervices.msc?

Comment: And doing so you have not provided enough information to both problems. What are the steps you have tried to solve the Sql Server Express problem? Where is the code that raises the exception on the textboxes? Better focus on a problem at time and give all the necessary information in a well prepared question. By the way, asking questions is free.

Comment: mostly was try to update it, which I did. Or restart the program/computer and see if it works again.  Also, edited the post with the code.

Asking questions is free, but there is a security which prevents to make too many posts. I tried to make an other question to see if I Can, and I cant ask an other question in 3 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Sql thats sql server error so, try to connect after some time.
or you can check in services window for SQL server,  if it is stoped than start it.

And for textbox, pls make sure your code file dosen't have any method which use textbox1 and then rebuild your project and run it again.

Comment: did you check your SQL server is running or not? in services

Comment: @shekhpar patel Yes I did check all the services. 
when create a local DB, it works. but when try to connect to the online db. It continues to show problems